# Recommended minimal open port configuration on a public IP

Tags: firewall, linux-networking, port

Let's assume a Linux server with a public IP which is assigned to it by an ISP
(or some other server) and the general rule / mindset to close all unnecessary ports / protocols.

Obviously ports related to the services offered should be kept open, i.e.
a web server should probably be reachable on TCP 80, 443, 8080, etc.
And let's add ssh for administration to the "obvious group" as well.
This is not the point of this question.

**Is there a list of ports / protocols that should be kept open in order for the server to function properly inside its network?**

Examples:
Maybe UDP 68, in case the ISP or network DHCP server wants to reassign a new IP?
Probably ICMP for network trouble shooting?

I realize this is to a certain degree opinion, but maybe there is a general consensus. Thank you.

Comment: don't keep *ANY* ports open unless needed and if you're plan to keep port 22 open for ssh, I would recommend change it to some other one...

Comment: @alexus: thanks for your comment, so nothing is really needed? In case your DHCP server wants to assign you a new IP, it just waits for the next pull of your DHCP client? I absolutely agree that a ssh passwd auth w/ unlimited trials is a bad idea, but a non-standard port is probably the weakest solution, compared to a key auth, 2 factor auth, and / or proper fail2ban or iptables recent blocks. But I didn't want this question to be about ssh passwd brute force attack mitigation :)

Comment: The DHCP server does not send the information, the client requests it.

Comment: By default, firewalls close all ports, that is the minimum needed for a network. Simply open any ports necessary to allow any applications to functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previous answers state, you should keep all port closed unless needed.

I would like to add two other aspects:

- Connectivity: I would make sure keep ICMP allowed (this is not exactly a port to open, but something to make sure you are not firewalling), as there are network tuning that need it (as stated by this [nice article](https://mellowd.co.uk/ccie/?p=5531) and also [this one](http://www.znep.com/~marcs/mtu/)). ICMP is not only for `ping` and diagnostics.
- Security: I would recommend to always have some sort of front-end device or host in front of a server with an all-purpose operating system. Any kind of firewalling device, or even an properly configured router will greatly reduce the attach surface, and relax (but not make dissappear) the need to keep your server really up-to-date with patches for kernel and network stack software.

Hope it helps!

Comment: ICMP doesn't have ports, it uses query identifiers. _Some_ transport protocols (TCP, UDP) use addressing called ports, but most use some other addressing or none at all. The ports are exclusive to the transport protocol used, so UDP and TCP could use the same port number, even in translation, but they would not actually be the same port.

Comment: Sure, ICMP traffic does not have a concept of ports like TCP or UDP (that is why I made "not exactly a port to open"), but have types/code that can be filtered. In my answer, I brougth it in for two reasons: the OP mentioned ICMP as something to filter, and the fact that many firewall solutions (`ufw`, `firewalld`, etc) may have defaults that deny several ICMP useful types, specifically those related to MTU discovery.

Answer (score 0):

Close off all ports by default.  Ideally you would have a firewall device between the Linux server and the ISP to provide for NAT/PAT, traffic inspection, access rules, etc.  You will want that granular level of control and there are a lot of firewall options.  You could then establish a VPN connection to the firewall and then administer the server "privately" rather than across the public Internet.  My 2 cents.